# Port Number 'mangle' when importing CSV into Excel 2010

Tags: python, excel, csv, ciscoconfparse

**Update**: I'm now seeing CSV writer correctly parsing the port numbers, even with using the dialect='excel'. Not sure what I was seeing earlier but it clearly was NOT doing so earlier. I have to consider it suspect until proven otherwise. At any rate, I'm open to ideas to try...

I'm using CiscoConfParse to parse multiple files and writing a CSV file with the information split into separate cells.  My problem is that port numbers look fine if they start with '0' i.e. '0/1', but the csv.writer does not correctly parse the port number otherwise.  For instance, '1/1' comes out 'Jan-00' when using dialect='excel' as below.

Here is my code at this point:

```
import os
import re
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse 
import csv

def main():

    path="K:\\Temp work\\120\\New\\Configs\\Working\\"  # insert (\\) the path to the directory of interest   
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path)):
        for f in os.listdir(path):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, f)
            out_file = 'PC.csv'  # change to the name of the file to be created
            fo = open(out_file, "ab")
            fWriter = csv.writer(fo, dialect='excel')
            fWriter.writerow([f])

            with open(file_path, "r"):
                parse = CiscoConfParse(file_path)
                vlanList = parse.find_blocks("(?i)^interface [Pp]")
                for line in vlanList:
                    lod = re.split(r'\s*',line)
                    writer = csv.writer(fo, delimiter=",", dialect='excel') 
                    writer.writerow(lod)

            fo.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

When I change the code to include the following...

```
csv.register_dialect('singlequote', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

...and change to dialect='singlequote' the CSV is parsed correctly when viewed in a text editor.  I then import into Excel and while everything is there correctly, it has the single quotes of course.

Unfortunately, I don't want the single quotes at this point.  I've selected all and formatted as text, then do a replace on the quote character with 'nothing' and the single quotes leave but Excel then changes the fields to back to a date field and I'm back where I started. I could of course remove the quotes while still in CSV (text) file, but when that's imported into Excel - even if I manually import and specify that the fields are text, Excel will still override my formatting and make it a date. (Note: I have already tried turning off AutoCorrect in Excel)

Any suggestions?

Comment: hint: 'raw' string literals can ease the pain of adding double backslashes: `r"K:\here\there"`

Comment: Does this question boil down to 'when my csv file contains `1/1, "x", "y"`, excel interprets the first cell as a date'?